# Searching for a reference in multiple dll files

Tags: .net, search, dll, reference

Suppose you have a folder with 100 .NET dll files in it. Each of these dll files may or may not contain a reference to a certain .NET dll with a certain version number - for example, "MyCompany.MyCompanyProject.dll", version 1.2.0. How do you find out which dll files actually contain this reference? You could go through the files one by one using a tool such a Reflector, but is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should use reflection. But i can load thia assemblies as reflection-only.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("Source");
foreach (AssemblyName an in asm.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
    Display("Name={0}, Version={1}", an.Name, an.Version); 
}
```

Also, you can load them in another AppDomain and then dispose it.
It's not quick way, but your current AppDomain would be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some c# code, can be adapted for powershell if you don't have visual studio available.  You will require references to System.IO and System.Reflection.

```
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(f);
                Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(f);
                string asmName = asm.GetName().Name;
                Version asmVer = asm.GetName().Version;
            }
            catch (BadImageFormatException)
            {
                //swallow
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```